# Openshift/minishift Nodejs application Build error "javac not found"

Tags: openshift, minishift

I got the following build error for my nodejs application.

```
node-gyp rebuild
[node-java] Error: not found: javac
```

The package.json file has the following dependencies

```
>   "dependencies": {
>     "async": "^2.6.0",
>     "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
>     "express": "^4.16.2",
>     "jdbc": "^0.6.3",
>     "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
>     "lodash": "^4.17.5",
>     "node-stringify": "^0.2.1",
>     "nodeunit": "^0.11.2"   }
```

I am using docker.io/centos/nodejs-8-centos7 image to build my nodejs application.

Comment: In order words, how do I create a build image that will have both node+jdk?

Comment: Your post is missing some crucial information, like minishift/openshift version, are you using the build-in jenkins or a buildconfig w/o jenkins?
So I'll just refer to [jenkins-slaves](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/using_images/other_images/jenkins_slaves.html)